# How do you do a `git blame` from the command line on one line of code that I am interested in?

Tags: git, command-line

Essentially what I am trying to do is that same thing we usually do using the web interface. I know how to do `git blame` using the web interface say bitbucket or github, but how do you do the same thing using git CLI ? So far I have got thus far:

1. `git grep <line of code that I am interested to see the blame>`. Get a list of files then find the one that I am interested in.
2. `git blame <on file of interest>`. Shows who did what and commit hash.
3. Can't figure this part out ... I see the hash I am interested in, how do I see the full commit log on just that one commit hash ?

Answer (score 12):

I stumbled on this http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/02/git-blame-line-history/ after I posted this, so I am going to post this here for reference. The steps are:

1. Find the line number you are interested to find blame on and do `git blame -L <starting line number>,<ending line number> <filename>`. (i.e. line numbers are comma-separated, no space)
2. `git show <commit hash>` will show you what you need to know.

Comment: If the output should only contain one line, it has to be `-L <line number>,<line number>` or `-L <line number>,+1`. Otherwise the output contains everything starting with the given line number until the end of the file.